# As I expected / had expected / have expected

Tags: tense, exam-questions

> It is not such a pretty place as I (expected / had expected / have expected).

Which is the correct tense to use here ? I am not able to figure out any difference in the meaning of the three difference tenses used here.

Edit : I used google translate to translate it in my native language, *have expected* sounds wrong to me here but still *had expected* and *expected* seem to convey almost same meaning.

Comment: both "expected" and "had expected" are grammatical but mean slightly different things, so you'll have to add more details

Comment: Google Translate is extremely unreliable. Read [this answer for another language](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4352/118) about how Google Translate works, and you'll see why its translations have no clue about grammar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are right that **I have expected** is incorrect, since **have** relates to a completed action, and **expect** is not really an action.

**I expected** is [past simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/past-continuous-and-past-simple), and relates to something that happened before now. **I had expected** is [past perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/past-perfect), which relates to something that happened before some event in the past.

The verb **is** is present, so we are talking about the situation now: what we expected is before now, so simple past is correct.

> It **is** not such a pretty place as I expected.

You might use present perfect if the main verb were in the past, though past simple would also work, because there is no real event and what you expected is both before now and before the **was**.

> It **was** not such a pretty place as I had expected.
>   It **was** not such a pretty place as I expected.

Comment: It's also possible to say "as I had been expecting" or "as I have been expecting", but with a very specific nuance.

Comment: @Andrew, true: what do you think that the nuance is?

Comment: Maybe the continuous tenses stress more on the expectation of the subject? Like when a kid is really expecting their Christmas gift is an iPad, which turns out is not?

Answer (score 1):

**Correct:** It is not such a pretty place as I expected.

**'as I expected'** is an idiom.
In line expression may like:

```
She's not so old-looking as I expected.
```

More info: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+I+expected